# Expansion file unable to download when app is published

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I manually wanted to download the expansion file for published app from the PlayStore.
 
Naming convention used for the expansion file.
`main.6.com.package.name.obb`
The Version code and file size used for downloading the obb file

```
private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
        new XAPKFile(
                true, // true signifies a main file
                6, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded
                // against
                977330086L // the length of the file in bytes
        )
};
```

The version for the apk is 6 and file size is 977330086 bytes. 
The BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY is 
`private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "Base64-encoded RSA public key";
    // used by the preference obfuscater
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
           1, 43, -12, -1, 54, 98,
            -100, -12, 43, 2, -8, -4, 9, 5, -106, -108, -33, 45, -1, 84
    };`

Manifest file for the app is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0"
>
```

App is now published in the playstore .Unable to download the obb file and displays.Tried in Beta testing it too displays same over there.

> Download failed because the resource could not be found.